# How does foreigner registration in Slovenia work?

Tags: paperwork, eu-citizens, registration, slovenia, freedom-of-movement

[The FCO advice for Slovenia notes that:](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/slovenia/local-laws-and-customs)

> All foreign nationals visiting Slovenia must register with the Police within 3 days of arrival or risk paying a fine. If you are staying at a registered hotel or guest house, they will register you when processing your arrival. If you are staying in self-catering accommodation, check registration arrangements with your booking agent If you are staying with friends or family, you or your host will need to visit the nearest police station to register your presence in Slovenia.

Can anyone provide further information on how one goes about this, and what sort of information is required as part of the registration?

Also, if we are staying in a small alpine/tourist town (but indeed in self-catering accommodation, probably not through a major agency) is it likely that we can do this in the town or might we have to travel a long distance (in Slovenian terms) to be able to register?

Do we need to re-register if we move?

For bonus points, explain how this law can be compatible with [EU freedom of movement laws stating that](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/policies/citizenship/docs/guide_free_movement_low.pdf):

> Every EU citizen has the right to reside on the territory of the host EU country for a period of up to three months without any conditions or formalities other than the requirement to hold a valid identity card or passport.

(Page 14)

Comment: In Czech Republic there is an exception for EU citizens: they must register after 30 days and there's no penalty for failing to do so.

Comment: @JonathanReez EU citizens must register  *within* (not after) 30 days after entering Czech Republic. [What's the point in registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/129823/1810)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For EU citizens:**

According to the [Slovenian Ministry of the Interior](http://www.mnz.gov.si/en/services/slovenia_your_new_country/entering_the_country/citizens_of_eu_and_eea/):

> If you are a member of a EU and EEA country you may enter the Republic of Slovenia with a valid identity card or a valid passport and you are not required to obtain an entry permit, i.e. a visa or a residence permit. **For the first three months after entry, you may stay without residence registration**, while for a longer stay you are required to register your residence, i.e. submit an application for the issue of a residence registration certificate at the administrative unit in the area of your residence before the expiry of the permitted three-month stay. You can of course also apply for the issue of a residence registration certificate immediately upon your entry into the country.

So the answer is: EU nationals have 3 months to complete their registration.

**For other nationals:**

According to a [document](http://www.mnz.gov.si/fileadmin/mnz.gov.si/pageuploads/DUNZ/Tujci/Certificate_of_registered_residence.doc) on the same website:

> Should you not be staying in tourist, hospitality or accommodation facilities, you are obliged to register yourself at the competent police authority within 3 days following the crossing of the national border and accommodation change, respectively. Should you stay in tourist or hospitality facilities, the landlords of such facilities are obliged to submit your registration to the competent police authority within 12 hours following your reception; should you stay in accommodation facilities, the landlords of such facilities are obliged to submit your registration to the competent police authority within 3 days following your reception.

So the answer is: if you're staying at any commercial property, the owner of the property is obliged to register you with the Ministry of the Interior. Therefore you should only be concerned with registration if staying at a friend's place.

Comment: Strange that the FCO advice (intended for UK citizens) tell you to register then. I've seen other UK travel advice sites warning of fines if you don't do this visitor registration. Sounds like it's the landlords issue, not ours however.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation in Croatia. The US Department of State travel advice said you had to register at a police station, but my Airbnb host told me she just needed to fill out an online form and upload a scan the ID page of my passport.

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be a difference between registering your presence, and registering your residence. The former is allowed within the first 3 months, the latter is not.

> Directive 2004/38/EC, Article 5
>
> 5. The Member State may require the person concerned to report his/her presence within its territory within a reasonable and
>    non-discriminatory period of time. Failure to comply with this
>    requirement may make the person concerned liable to proportionate and
>    non-discriminatory sanctions.

source: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:en:PDF

> Until you obtain a residence registration certificate you must fulfil
> the obligation of registration with the police defined by the
> Residence Registration Act. If you are not accommodated in a tourist,
> catering or other accommodation facility, you need to register with
> the competent police station on your own within 3 days after crossing
> the state border and after changing accommodation. If you are
> accommodated in a tourist or catering facility, the keeper needs to
> register you with the competent police station within 12 hours after
> your reception. However, if you stay in an accommodation facility,
> your landlord is obliged to register you with the competent police
> station within 3 days after reception.

source: http://www.infotujci.si/s/7/eu-and-eea-citizens

Comment: Does the law mention any penalties for failing to register?

Answer (score 2):

The practical implementation of this, is that every where we stayed, the owner/manager asked to see our passports, and took copies. They asked a couple of questions two, always the same ones, clearly to fill in some part of the form.

I never asked how this was compatible with the freedom of movement rules (not meeting any Slovenian legislators) - possibly because the process was just checking that we had a valid passport or identity card?