# What's the penalty for avoiding to register with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?

Tags: paperwork, europe, czech-republic, registration

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63991/1810):

> In Czech Republic there is an exception for EU citizens: they must register  <s>after</s> within 30 days and there's no penalty for failing to do so. – [JonathanReez♦](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez) ↵ Feb 18 '16 at 10:35

What's the point in registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic?

---

For an official source: https://www.policie.cz/clanek/reporting-of-the-place-of-aliens-residence.aspx

> An EU citizen is obliged, within 30 days from his/her entry into the Territory, to report the place of his/her residence in the Territory to the police if his/her expected stay is to be longer than 30 days; this obligation also applies to an EU citizen's family member if that EU citizen is staying in the Territory. The obligation to report the place of residence to the police does not apply to an alien who has fulfilled this obligation with the accommodation provider.

Another official source: https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/entering-the-czech-republic.aspx:

> One of the obligations ensuing from the [Act on the Residence of Foreign Nationals](http://aplikace.mvcr.cz/sbirka-zakonu/ViewFile.aspx?type=c&id=5978) (pdf, 1 MB) for citizens of the EU, Iceland, Norway, Liechtenstein, or Switzerland is the "reporting requirement" in the event that the length of the intended stay in the Czech Republic is longer than 30 days. In this situation, within 30 days of entering the Czech Republic, an individual is required to report his/her presence to the appropriate [Foreign Police Department](http://www.policie.cz/clanek/oddeleni-pobytovych-agend.aspx) that holds jurisdiction in the location of his/her stay in the Czech Republic.

Comment: A law with no penalty is still a law.

Comment: @o.m. what happens if you don't follow it?

Comment: You have broken the law. Most people follow the law because it is the law, not because of the specific penalty.

Comment: @o.m. I see. Aside from this, is there any upside in registering?

Comment: It is a matter of policy on Travel Stack Exchange that we advise following the law ;:-)

Comment: @o.m. I don't necessarily plan to break it. I'm just curious about the upsides of registering in addition to respecting the law. This way it'll help me decide whether to wait 30 days.

Comment: Other than that, it becomes a question of the certain effort of registering vs. the uncertain effort of sorting things out *if* there are questions. 30 days in one place, what are the odds that you get a traffic ticket and get asked, "where do you live currently?"

Comment: @o.m. I rather suspect that most people break the law because they do not know all of the laws and so cannot follow them all.

Comment: I'm flagging that as belonging to Expatriates, because long stays qualify you as resident. Residents must generally register anywhere ....

Comment: @DanubianSailor the point is that a tourist or business visit of between 30 days and 3 months triggers the requirement to register under Czech law while remaining within the three-month period within which EU citizens can visit without having to prove their entitlement to the right of residence for more than three months under the free movement directive (and, supposedly, without having to register). An extended vacation or business visit of five to thirteen weeks does not really qualify for Expatriates.

Comment: @phoog the obligation of registering after 30 days is the clear indicator that some countries (Czech Republic in that case) see that otherwise. And everything connected with registration is more likely to get better answers on Expatriates.

Comment: @DanubianSailor have you seen the "registration" tag on travel.se?

Comment: @DanubianSailor as I understand it, the 30-day registration requirement refers to a different category of registration from the three-month registration requirement, namely the Art 5(5) reporting of presence, as outlined in [an answer to the related question about Slovenia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/68859/19400).  That is not tied to long-term stays and enforcing such a requirement does not imply that the person concerned is an expatriate.

Comment: Could the 2 primarily opinion-based close voters please explain their vote? I don't see any opinion.

Comment: I updated the title to be less opinion based.

Comment: @JonathanReez the original question seemed to imply that it was asking for benefits that might be realized by applying earlier than 30 days. Perhaps it would be better to ask about both penalties for late registration and benefits of early registration, but I can't think of a concise way to ask that just now.

Comment: @phoog correct. I think it's two different questions, so I'll ask a second one just one the upside of registering early (I don't see how that's opinion-based but happy to be contradicted)

Comment: Follow-up question: [Is there any upside in applying earlier than 30 days when registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/130015/1810)

Comment: Why is this not eavily downvoted and closed? Last time I asked about medical insurance in the UK I was immediately sent to Expatriates with a wave of downvotes.

Comment: @VladimirF because staying somewhere for 40 days doesn't make you an expat. Have you read the comments above?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It wouldn't even cross my mind that a simple visitor not emplyoed here would register. No-one does that, it is an extremely annoying procedure even for those that do work here.

Comment: @VladimirF hence my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I've managed to find the full rules governing the registration of EU citizens. According to law number 326/1999, paragraph 93:

> (2) Občan Evropské unie je povinen ohlásit na policii místo pobytu na území ve lhůtě do 30 dnů ode dne vstupu na území, pokud jeho předpokládaný pobyt bude delší než 30 dnů; tato povinnost se rovněž vztahuje na rodinného příslušníka občana Evropské unie, pokud tento občan pobývá na území. Povinnost ohlásit místo pobytu na policii se nevztahuje na cizince, který tuto povinnost splnil u ubytovatele.

Which translates to:

> The citizen of the European Union is obliged to report to the police the place of residence within the territory within 30 days from the date of entry into the territory if his expected stay is longer than 30 days; this obligation also applies to a family member of a citizen of the European Union if he resides in the territory. The obligation to report the place of residence to the police does not apply to an alien who has fulfilled this obligation through the property owner.

The penalty for violating this rule is spelled out in paragraph 156:

> (1) Cizinec se dopustí přestupku tím, že ...
>
> d) nesplní povinnost podle § 93 odst. 1 nebo 2 anebo podle § 98 odst. 1, 3, 4 nebo 5.

Which translates to:

> Foreigners commit a misdemeanour if they fail to fulfill their obligations according to paragraph 93 or 98.

And the punishment for this misdemeanour is:

> (5) Za přestupek lze uložit pokutu do
>
> d) 3000 Kč, jde-li o přestupek podle odstavce 1 písm. a), b), d), e), g) nebo k).

Which translates to:

> Misdemeanours mentioned in sections a), b), d), e), g) or k) shall be punished by a **fine up to 3000 CZK**.

So you are potentially liable to pay a small fine if you fail to register. Note that you don't need to explicitly register if staying in a hotel or short-term rental, as the property owner should do this for you.

Comment: Thanks! In the law you quote, do  citizens of the European Union count as Foreigners? Just asking as https://www.policie.cz/clanek/reporting-of-the-place-of-aliens-residence.aspx opposes aliens to EU citizens, and they only mention a fine of up to 3 000 CZK for aliens.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, EU citizens are foreigners according to this law

Comment: So it seems this requirement does not apply to Czech citizens who reside abroad.  Is there a parallel requirement created somewhere else? If not, the requirement seems discriminatory and therefore contrary to article 5(5).  (For example, Germany and the Netherlands have a municipal registration requirement that also applies to their own citizens.)

Comment: @phoog not that I can find. Czech citizens technically don't have to be registered anywhere at all, even if they live in the country.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder whether this has gone to the EU courts.

Comment: @phoog practically speaking this rule is never enforced in regards to EU citizens. I know people who live in Prague for a decade without ever announcing their presence to Czech authorities. And without someone getting penalized there's no basis for a lawsuit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is at risk of being closed, I'm writing down what I found so far in this answer. The following sources indicate the need to register with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen:

- https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/third-country-nationals-entering-the-czech-republic.aspx
- https://www.policie.cz/clanek/reporting-of-the-place-of-aliens-residence.aspx
- https://movetoprague.com/foreign-police-prague/

None of them mentioned any upside for the citizen, so as far as I can see so far, there is **no upside in registering** aside from the sake of respecting a regulation (that JonathanReez reports as no having no penalty if not followed).