# Is there any upside in applying earlier than 30 days when registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?

Tags: paperwork, europe, czech-republic, registration

https://www.policie.cz/clanek/reporting-of-the-place-of-aliens-residence.aspx states that:

> An EU citizen is obliged, within 30 days from his/her entry into the Territory, to report the place of his/her residence in the Territory to the police if his/her expected stay is to be longer than 30 days; this obligation also applies to an EU citizen's family member if that EU citizen is staying in the Territory. The obligation to report the place of residence to the police does not apply to an alien who has fulfilled this obligation with the accommodation provider.

Is there any upside in applying earlier than 30 days when registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?

Comment: The cited quote says about **expected** stay... doesn't it answer your question? You are expected to register if you plan to stay longer than 30 days...

Comment: @DanubianSailor No, my question is: is there any upside in applying earlier than 30 days (vs. waiting on the 30th day) when registering with the police when visiting Czech Republic as a EU citizen?

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be busy on day 30, then the upside of reporting your presence earlier than that is that **then your plans for day 30 will not need to be interrupted or changed** to make time to go to the police.